# Why is the name of the first Hebrew letter also the word for 1000?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, aleph-bet-letters

I find it interesting the first letter in the Hebrew alphabet is "Aleph", which shares the letters and is pronounced nearly identically to the word for one thousand - "Eleph".

Why might this be?

Where does the root A-L-F (אלף) really come from? What  meaning is ascribed to this in Judaism?

Comment: There is somthing to it ,from aleph to eleph,Rav Munk explains the gemara in Sotah 8b a brick by brick a house is built ,penny by penny a fortune is amassed,from small beg come great thing that is the lesson of aleph to eleph,also Aluph means Master,this is a reasonable question which has a reasonable answer

Comment: I agree the gemara in Shabbas darshans the aleph bais ,like Osios Rabbi Akiva